# Contar palavras em arquivo CSV

Tags: python, csv

Estou tentando ler um arquivo CSV e criar uma lista com todas as palavras do arquivo e a quantidade de vezes que ela aparece. Originalmente o arquivo era em PDF, mas julguei que poderia ser mais simples a leitura em csv. Estou usando o Google Collab.
Comecei procurando essa informação no Stack Overflow em EN e fiz uma pequena adaptação para o Google Colab, já que preciso importar o arquivo.

```
import csv
from google.colab import files
from collections import Counter
from collections import defaultdict

words= []
arquivo = files.upload()

with open(str(arquivo), 'rt') as csvfile: #aqui eu coloquei a variável arquivo em str
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    next(reader)
    for col in reader:
         csv_words = col[0].split(" ")
         for i in csv_words:
              words.append(i)
```

Já recebi o *erro "File name is too long" (OSERROR 36)*. Não sei como continuar daqui. Se alguém puder me orientar, agradeço!

Bom final de semana para todos.

Comment: pode disponibilizar arquivo de exemplo?

Comment: @Lucas, o link para o arquivo teste é https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tJ0Ri1exQwG15zce7orOIBVhlWRdtOI8/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mano, fiz no Pycharm, mas será fácil jogar no collab.

Obs: Como Python é case sensitive, ou seja, um 'a' minusculo é diferente de 'A' maiusculo, talvez colocar um upper ou lower melhore a analise e remover os acentos, deixei a biblioteca e exemplo abaixo comentada ( unicodedata )

```
import csv

words = dict()
arquivo = 'teste_arquivo1.csv'

with open(arquivo, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:  # aqui eu coloquei a variável arquivo em str
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:

        for palavra in row[0].split():

            # Se existir é verdadeiro
            if palavra in words:
                words[palavra] = int(words[palavra]) + 1
            else:
                words[palavra] = 1

# Imprime o dicionario
print(words)

print()

# For do dicionario por linha
for chave, valor in words.items():
    print('Palavra = ' + str(chave)+((20-len(str(chave)))*' ') + ' - Quantidade = ' + str(valor))

'''
from unicodedata import normalize

def remover_acentos(txt, codif='utf-8'):
    palavra =  normalize('NFKD', txt).encode('ASCII', 'ignore').decode('ASCII')
    
    #Minusculo 
    palavra = palavra.lower()
    
    return palavra
    
print(remover_acentos('gráfico'))   
'''
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]